# c# ItemDataBound new event handler

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
    protected virtual void DataGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
    {
      this.list = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("edit_list");
      if (list != null)
      {
         list.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(List_SelectedIndexChanged);
       }     
    }
```

List is assigned, but selectedIndex eventHandler won't work
if i make `RepairsStateList.BackColor = Color.Black;` it is working

```
protected void List_SelectedIndexChanged(object source, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("<script>alert('vv') </script>");
}
```

Comment: when you debug the code..? is this event being fired.. DataGrid1_ItemDataBound ..?

Comment: I see that you are doing list.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(List_SelectedIndexChange) where is the Event Code block for that as well..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AutoPostBack` property of this dropdown must be set to true...

than you code must be

```
protected void dropdownlist1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)    {        
// get reference to the row
GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(((Control)sender).NamingContainer);   

// Get the reference of this DropDownlist
DropDownList dropdownlist1 = (DropDownList) gvr.FindControl("dropdownlist1");

}
```

**Edit**

Replace this line with

```
this.list = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("edit_list");
```

this

```
  DropDownList list = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("edit_list");
  if (list != null)
  {
     list.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(List_SelectedIndexChanged);
   }
```